# Iframe widget on clients website and authentication for API

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, reactjs, iframe

I'm building an application in which users can receive a javascript line that they can embed on their own website to load a widget and make certain information available to the website visitors and allow interaction from the end users.

The widget is a javascript that loads in an iframe from a page that is hosted on my server. The page is a react front-end that talks my .NET backend through API. In the url I get the users id to know which widget to load. www.example.com/widget/userid

The widget doesn't require the end users to sign in or get authenticated however, I don't want to make my APIs public and I need authentication at least from my own users before they receive the javascript that they can embed or any other practice someone can suggest.

What would be the best practice for authentications for the APIs that the page can talk to even when its loaded in the iframe on my users websites and doesn't require my users website visitors to sign in?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should use postmessage.
In the sender side:

```
parent.postMessage({ type: 'something',more data...}, '*')
```

and then on the receiver side you can do:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  switch (event.data.type) {
      case 'something':
      // Do something
      break;
  }
}
```

This way you can make an iFrame communicate with other JS element.

Hope it some how helps.